# JSON conversion from server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm working on a app that get a data using json representation and converts it to a foundation object using NSJSONSerialization.

My problem comes after getting the data from the server. This is an example of a respond:

> {"groups":{"15":{"idgroupcat":"15","name":"\u05e7\u05d1\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4
>   1","mains":{"9":{"idmaincat":"9","name":"\u05e8\u05d0\u05e9\u05d9
>   1","subs":{"12":{"idsubcat":"12","idcategory":"23","name":"\u05ea\u05ea
>   1","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}},"16":{"idgroupcat":"16","name":"group
>   1","mains":{"10":{"idmaincat":"10","name":"main
>   1","subs":{"13":{"idsubcat":"13","idcategory":"24","name":"sub
>   1","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}},"11":{"idmaincat":"11","name":"main
>   2","subs":{"14":{"idsubcat":"14","idcategory":"25","name":"sub
>   2","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}},"13":{"idmaincat":"13","name":"main
>   2","subs":{"16":{"idsubcat":"16","idcategory":"26","name":"sub
>   2","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}},"14":{"idmaincat":"14","name":"main
>   2","subs":{"17":{"idsubcat":"17","idcategory":"27","name":"sub
>   2","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}},"15":{"idmaincat":"15","name":"main
>   2","subs":{"18":{"idsubcat":"18","idcategory":"28","name":"sub
>   2","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"},"23":{"idsubcat":"23","idcategory":"31","name":"sub
>   8","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"},"24":{"idsubcat":"24","idcategory":"32","name":"sub
>   8","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}},"17":{"idgroupcat":"17","name":"group
>   2","mains":{"19":{"idmaincat":"19","name":"main
>   4","subs":{"22":{"idsubcat":"22","idcategory":"30","name":"sub
>   6","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}},"19":{"idgroupcat":"19","name":"group
>   2","mains":{"18":{"idmaincat":"18","name":"main
>   3","subs":{"21":{"idsubcat":"21","idcategory":"29","name":"sub
>   3","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}},"20":{"idgroupcat":"20","name":"group
>   2","mains":{"20":{"idmaincat":"20","name":"main
>   3","subs":{"25":{"idsubcat":"25","idcategory":"33","name":"sub
>   3","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}},"21":{"idgroupcat":"21","name":"group
>   2","mains":{"21":{"idmaincat":"21","name":"main
>   3","subs":{"26":{"idsubcat":"26","idcategory":"34","name":"sub
>   3","title":"","workpicurl":"","numberofprofs":null,"numberofworks":null,"averageapplicationsperwork":null,"averagecloseprice":null,"averagewhen":"0"}}}}}}}

Once i try to convert this using NSJSONSerialization it returns null

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

And if i use the method to see if this is a valid json object, the method return NO.

I know that the problem is in the server response but i don't know what input to give the programmer about the specific problem. The server is written in php

Any advice?
Thanks,

Comment: What error is returned in the error variable err?

Comment: The error is important, it is valid JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

Comment: That's why jsonlint was slow for me just now, all of SO is using it.  :-)  Would also be helpful to see the few lines leading up to the JSON deserialization, to prove that data1 is really the NSData for the posted string.

Comment: Quite likely to be an issue putting the JSON string into data - most probably because of using the wrong string encoding. Need to see more code.

Comment: data1 is the data received from the delegate methods of NSURLConection, there isn't any other lines of code leading to it. The string output i have at the question is after converting data1 to a string object rather into a Dictionary/Array

Comment: David Doyle, do you mean on the app side or on the server side?

Comment: I mean on the app side. This may require seeing more source code - the JSON is definitely valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the id group 15, there is some unknown character (by me) thata is not correctly rendered. try with this fix on the server php file, just before the call to the output method:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($yourDataObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a bit of digging in the code.

The problem arise in the server side with the coding of the response. To solve this the utf-8 header was added to the response. This fixed the problem and the string now can be converted into a foundation object.

Answer (score 0):

Json decoder from Zend Framework 1 work ok with JSON you provided:

```
    $phpNative = Zend_Json::decode($yourJSON, Zend_Json::TYPE_OBJECT);
```

I do copy-paste to $yourJSON